# Translation service

Tags: discussion

#### Posting in other languages, please be friendly but clear

The subject must be as old Santa, but there *still* seems to be a lot of misunderstanding on the subject:

Every now and then people post in other languages than English, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588341/i-cannot-install-ubuntu#comment816638_588341). I tend to leave a (IMO rather friendly) comment, saying:
"*Please see this https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3616/72216 - questions should be asked and responded to in english. Thank-you.*"

This is not a political statement, not a value label, just a reminder of the practical agreement we have that this site is in English.

Also every now and then, I get a grumpy comment suggesting (like in the example) That I should rather translate the post. The comment is even upvoted.(?)
Please don't leave a comment suggesting so, it gives people the wrong impression that we are running a translation service here.
We do not ask people to write a poem in English, and most of us are willing to do some editing if the language is a bit of a problem but the question is clear.

But again:
Don't suggest we *should* translate a question, and publically suggest it is "unfriendly" to ask people to post in English.

Comment: I agree although I sometimes too try to translate Spanish/French/German posts to English, but always with leaving a comment that the OP has to use English here at least for his/her next post.

Comment: @ByteCommander I think that is perfectly allright, than you make clear it is not what we *should* do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting a question in English (outside of being policy) is the best way to get the maximum number of eyeballs on a problem and increases the odds of a solution. I'm baffled as to why anyone would think that request unfriendly. I've made attempts with translation services in the past but considering the results I should have just left a comment suggesting conversion to english and perhaps flagged unclear what you are asking....

Answer (score 0):

Why not leave such posts as they look like?

Those one who have big right gold opinion will down vote.
Others will ignore or translate manually.

Answer (score -1):

I would put that as a `feature-request` then.  Normally I would control paste the text into google translate and fix the context.  But if theres a way to put it into SE without doing it automatically I would support it.

Comment: When I started participating on AU, I used to suggest to use Google translate. However, If you look into the history of the question, you can see what happens then. It creates a dragon of a translation, and still needs *a lot* of editing (which I did in this case by the way). Usually, a story by OP in his or her own words does the job better, even if the skills on English are limited. I'd rather read a authentic question than a weirdly translated one.

Comment: @JacobVlijm - When I have to do it I edit in the (google) translated version and a comment that I use online translation, and **leave the original** (in a blockquote), so anyone who can speak the language can read it and do a proper translation without having to look in the revision history.

Comment: @JacobVlijm "a dragon of a translation" = "een draak van een vertaling" :)

Comment: @don.joey I was wondering if it would work in English :).

Comment: Automated translation services are not always totally accurate. Unless you have a good grasp of the language that you're translating, then I'd say it's probably better to just leave the question to someone else - ideally, the OP.